# Timeout old sessions with Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, security, session, devise

I'm using Devise to manage login for my Rails app. I want to set a maximum session length: the user will be forced to log in again after 10 hours.

nb this is **not Timeoutable**. Timeoutable sets a session expiry for an inactive session. eg if the user hasn't clicked a link in 30 minutes, it will log them out.

I want to expire even an active session, with a longer timeout than my Timeoutable period.

Answer (score 1):

You will need custom logic to accomplish this behavior, as Devise doesn't provide this functionality.

For example, you can try to use something like this: https://github.com/markets/sudo_rails. With this gem, you can require your users to enter again the password for some sensible actions (or your whole app) by using the `sudo` macro in your controller:

```rb
class ProtectedController < ApplicationController
  sudo
end
```

[image]

In fact, you're not destroying the session, but requiring your users to validate the password again (for all actions under `ProtectedController`).

It comes with Devise integration and you also can define a custom session duration:

```rb
# config/initializers/sudo_rails.rb
SudoRails.setup do |config|
  config.sudo_session_duration = 10.hours
end
```

Comment: Thanks. I really want to terminate the session rather than gatekeep one or more actions. You've confirmed thought that it'll need a custome approach and custom code. Not the answer I'd hoped for but yes the one I'd expected.